# Hibernate Migration 3.2 to 5.2.8: SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, migration

I am migrating my application from 3.2 to 5.2.8. I got alsmost everything sorted out except this strange exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3188) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 6.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildParamTypeDefinitions(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:260) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildPreparedStrings(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:219) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doPrepExec(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:612) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:400) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314) ~[sqljdbc4.jar!/:?]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493) ~[?:?]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3188) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
```

The query is

```
update TAB_A set COL1=?,COL2=?,COL3=?,COL4=?,COL5=?,COL6=?,COL7=?,COL8=?,COL9=?,COL10=? 
where ID=? and COL1=?
```

I see the same problem for simple select statements too.

This is a working application migrated to 5.2, so everything worked in 3.2. Any idea what am I missing? Please help.

Comment: please add the hql query that executes that statement.. with params setting etc..

Comment: Hi @MaciejKowalski the SQL I posted was generated by the saveOrUpdate(entity) method. I do not have the HQL for it. Also, I noticed today that if I comment out setMaxResults on the select HQLs then there is no issue. Any idea why this change in behavior? But I need setMaxResults for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a user error on my side. I had a custom UserType defined in the mapping file and during Hibernate upgrade I left the new nullSafeGet/Set unimplemented.

How I figured out? Debugging the SQL driver source showed that one of the custom types were not set in the prepared statement.

Thanks for all the response.